# Lost Vista partition on dual boot with 16.04

Tags: partitioning

I partitioned my Vista drive and installed 16.04 on second partition and it was working fine. The small boot window at startup listed Vista to boot first and I wanted it to boot Ubuntu first. At some point I had a window offering me, what I thought was an option to boot Ubuntu first and I used the option and afterward I had no option to boot to Vista. I have tried a new grub menu tool and boot repair but they did not work. I am not at all familiar with how to use them. The "Disks" utility" shows just one partition. Is there any way to rescue the Vista? I have some important info on it

Thanks for the reply. `fdisk` info:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 55.9 GiB, 60022480896 bytes, 117231408 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x4801b076

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 115230719 115228672   55G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       115232766 117229567   1996802  975M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       115232768 117229567   1996800  975M 82 Linux swap / Solaris


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.5 GiB, 8002732032 bytes, 15630336 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       32 15630335 15630304  7.5G  b W95 FAT32
```

Also, my question is not the same as [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu),
because I partitioned my drive and installations were fine. My mistake was trying to change the boot order.

Comment: It is unclear what you have done, but since Disks is showing just one partition, you may have deleted your Windows partition. Run `sudo fdisk -l`, copy the results from the terminal and edit your question adding the info.

Comment: My question was removed ? but it was not the same as a "duplicate".

Comment: I guess my question was removed because it was a duplicate?

Comment: My question was removed as a duplicate. But I lost my Vista part of my dual boot,which was working well when I tried to change boot order , I had the partition done correctly,Ubuntu offered me a way to boot ubuntu first and I may have lost athe windows partition, I'm not sure because you removed my question. Thanks

Comment: There's no Windows partition there. I suspect you reinstalled Ubuntu taking up all the disk and erasing everything else. It's probably late, but you could try testdisk to recover your lost partitions. It's quite technical. Look for a good tutorial before messing around with it.

Comment: @ToDo I'm not sure, but `sdb1` seems like a windows partition

Comment: Thanks Eliah,  I will try test disk,

Comment: Thanks Eliah, I did have the disk partitioned when I installed Ubuntu and it worked well for a few months . I lost the boot to Vista and probably it's partition when I used something in Ubuntu and it did not warn me that I would lose the partition. I think the devs should be aware of that , Thanks again for being the only one to help me.

Comment: For the devs to do remove any bugs, they would need to know what is this "something in Ubuntu" that caused the problem. You need to be more specific to receive attention.

Comment: Thanks ToDo and Eliah.

Comment: Thanks, I have not been able to run testdisk yet ,it appears to have been installed  but # testdisk  command only showed "sudo commands " list.

Comment: ran  "sudo # testdisk  and got this                                                  "  mo@mo-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-GA448UA-ABA:~$ sudo # testdisk
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p 
            prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] file .

Comment: You're running it as `sudo # testdisk`, you should remove the `#` symbol. Use `sudo testdisk` instead. Also, [edit] your post instead of adding a comment. It's better because you can format the command output so we can properly read it.